# How do I run a Workflow on a Task List as the Current User instead of Item Creator?

Tags: 2010, workflow, task-list

I've created a Workflow in SharePoint Foundation 2010.

It creates items in a task list. (Collect Data From User)

There is a workflow on the second task list that runs when the task is changed. For some reason this task is running as the task creator instead of the person who edited the task.

I need something like the impersonation step. I.E. I would like to impersonate the current user in the workflow.

Comment: Why don´t you use impersonate step in the second workflow?

Comment: @Lena The workflow needed to run as the person whom the task was assigned to, not the task creator, or workflow publisher.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I could find is to use a text field that was populated in Javascript with the display name of the currently logged in user, and use that value to update the information required within the workflow.